# non-numeric argument to binary operator error in r with plm and coeftest

Tags: r, plm

I am using `plm` to estimate my fixed effect model and using `coeftest` to get significance levels. `plm` was fine. However, when I was running `coeftest` (from package `lmtest`), I get this `Error in 1 - diaghat : non-numeric argument to binary operator`. Please find my model below.

```
# plm estimation was fine.
dd.panel.corn <- df.corn.year %>% 
  pdata.frame(index=c("index","Year")) %>% 
  plm(formula= log(yield.corn) ~ frez + dd + I(dd^2) + preci + I(preci^2) + 
        + w126_full + max.c + spei 
      + lt + qt, 
      data=., effect = c("individual"),model = "within")

# coeftest got an error.
ydd.panel.corn <- coeftest(dd.panel.corn, vcov = 
                           function(x) vcovHC(x, method = 'arellano', cluster = 'group', type = 'HC3'))
```

`frez` is freezing degree day variable. `dd` is growing degree day variable. `preci` is precipitation variable. `w126_full` is an index for ozone pollution. `max.c` is maximum temperature. `speci` is an indicator of drought.

Please let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Not reproducible with some artificial data for me. Can you check if the plain vcov function runs properly, i.e. check `vcovHC(dd.panel.corn, method = 'arellano', cluster = 'group', type = 'HC3')`. Next, you could use plm's summary() function with the vcov function: `summary(dd.panel.corn, vcov =  function(x) vcovHC(x, method = 'arellano', cluster = 'group', type = 'HC3'))`

Comment: @Helix123 Sorry for the late reply. I tried `vcovHC(dd.panel.corn, method = 'arellano', cluster = 'group', type = 'HC3')` and got the same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a chance to make the data available? With some artifical and with other data I have, everything works fine.